# Java String to Array

Tags: java, regex, arrays

I want to evaluate String like "`[1,5] [4,5] [10,6]`" in in array.

I'm not quite familiar with the Java regex and the syntax.

```
String game = "[1,5] [4,5] [10,6]"
Pattern splitter = Pattern.compile("\\[|,|\\]");
splitter.matcher(game);
public String [] gameArray = null;
gameArray = splitter.split(game);
```

I want to to iterate over each pair of array such as :  `[0][0] => 1; [0][1] => 5`

Comment: What is expected output from given String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(game, "[,] ");

while (st.hasMoreTokens())
{
    currentNumber = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    // fill array with it
}
```

It should be what you need, if I understood well

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
String game = "[1,5] [4,5] [10,6]";

 String[] arry=game.substring(1, game.length()-1).split("\\] +\\[");
 List<String[]> twoDim=new ArrayList<>();
 for (String string : arry) {
     String[] twoArr=string.split(",");
     twoDim.add(twoArr);
 }
 String[][] twoArr=twoDim.toArray(new String[0][0]);

 System.out.println(twoArr[0][0]); // 1
 System.out.println(twoArr[0][1]); // 5
```

Comment: @aetbaar_444, This one is goood, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html

Comment: @aetbaar_444, the above link is for tutorial, this one is regex builder. http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you need to split your string.
first of all you need to split on space and after that you need to split on ,(comma).and your third step will be remove brackets So at the end you will get you string into array.